# How to select first occurrence between two patterns including them

Tags: sed, awk, regular-expression

How can I select first occurrence between two patterns including them. Preferably using `sed` or `awk`.

I have:

```
text
something P1 something
content1
content2
something P2 something
text
something P1 something
content3
content4
something P2 something
text
```

I want the first occurrence of the lines between P1 and P2 (including P1 line and P2 line):

```
something P1 something
content1
content2
something P2 something
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
sed '/P1/,/P2/!d;/P2/q'
```

...would do the job portably by `d`eleting all lines which do `!`not fall within the range, then `q`uitting the first time it encounters the end of the range. It does not fail for P2 preceding P1, and it does not require GNU specific syntax to write simply.

Comment: Excellent! Much better than mine.

Comment: @muru - It is often easier to avoid contortions if you try to target the autoprint - let the cycle work for you. That's the habit I've fallen into anyway. I think it's probably best described as a *prune* vs a *select* method - I tend to wind up negating a pattern rather than searching for it.

Comment: This will hung when processing huge fileSize.

Comment: @Brain90 - shouldnt. if you can reliably reproduce your complaint you should address the maintainer of your `sed`... thats a bug in the `sed` youre running, and not in tbe script above.

Comment: Also works without the `/P2/q` bit.

Comment: @mikeserv I would not have said it if I wasn't.  Your concern over whether or not I care about a couple of characters is weird: I observed that the sed expression worked both with and without `/P2/q` on my system; that's it.  I was curious about something and wanted to share what I found.

Comment: for anyone used to using `|` separators in `sed` expressions (like myself): normally, `sed` accepts almost arbitrary separators (e.g. `sed -e 's|<string to match>|<string to replace>|g'` or `sed -e 's@<string to match>@<string to replace>@g'`); in this case, `sed` seems to insist on `/`, fails with e.g. `invalid command code |` otherwise

Answer (score 14):

In `sed`:

```
sed -n '/P1/,/P2/p; /P2/q'
```

- `-n` suppresses the default printing, and you print lines between the matching address ranges using the `p` command.
- Normally this would match both the sections, so you quit (`q`) when the first `P2` matches.

This will fail if a `P2` comes before `P1`. To handle that case, try:

```
sed -n '/P1/,/P2/{p; /P2/q}'
```

Comment: I disagree;  mikeserv’s answer is not any better than yours.

Comment: @g-man - pshaw.  but i was just thinking the same thing.

Comment: @gman - nope. now i get it. mines way better. no{ stack}!

Comment: You can avoid repeating the second pattern by using `$`, as in `sed -n '/P1/,${p;/P2/q}'`.

Comment: @SU3 what if P1=~P2?

Comment: @Erwann, my expression has the same behavior as the second one in muru's answer. If the first line that matches P1 also matches P2, the range consists only of that line. That may be the needed behavior or not depending on the use case.

Answer (score 12):

with `awk`

```
awk '/P1/{a=1};a;/P2/{exit}' file
something P1 something
content1
content2
something P2 something
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler `awk` solution (sort-of halfway between
[iruvar’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180663/80216#180676) and [muru’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180663/80216#180678), but not using a variable):

```
awk '/P1/,/P2/ { print }  /P2/ { exit }'
```

and, as muru noted,
if the first P2 appears before the first P1, this will print nothing.

Of course, if you want to print all the P1-P2 ranges:

```
something P1 something
content1
content2
something P2 something
something P1 something
content3
content4
something P2 something
```

just leave out the `exit` part:

```
awk '/P1/,/P2/ { print }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '/P1/,/P2/{print;f=1} f&&/P2/{exit}' data
```

Quit immediately after print, not before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip the patterns themselves, here is the `awk` version:

```
awk '/P2/ {exit} /P1/ {f=1; next} f' file
```

Comment: Works for me. Could you add some more info about how the command works?

Answer (score 0):

To skip the patterns themselves, and show only first matching block in single GNU sed:

```
sed -nre '/STARTPATTERN/ {:a;n;/ENDPATTERN/{b;};p;ba}' file
```

Comment: That prints _all_ matching blocks. For _first_ matching block: `sed -nE '/STARTPATTERN/ {:a;n;/ENDPATTERN/q;p;ba}' file`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/something P1/{f=1}/something P2/{f=0;print;exit}f'  file
```

output

```
something P1 something
content1
content2
something P2 something
```

Answer (score 0):

sed: (from @SU3's comment):

```
sed -n '/P1/,${p;/P2/q}'
```

awk:

```
awk '/P1/,0 {print; if ( /P2/ ) exit}' file
```

Both take the same approach: Within the range /P1/ to end of input, print and then exit if P2 is matched.

Both are DRY. P1 and P2 are specified only once.

Both pass the corner case of P2 preceding P1.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -ne 'state $i=0; .put if m/ P1 {last if $i++ == 1} /fff/ P2 /;'

#OR

raku -e 'my $i=0; .put if m/ P1 {last if $i++ == 1} /fff/ P2 / for lines;' 

#OR

raku -e 'my $i=0; for lines() { .put if m/ P1 {last if $i++ == 1} /fff/ P2 / };'
```

Sample Input:

```
text
something P1 something
content1
content2
something P2 something
text
something P1 something
content3
content4
something P2 something
text
```

Sample Output (1):

```
something P1 something
content1
content2
something P2 something
```

The above answer is coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Explaining the first answer briefly, Raku's non-autoprinting `-ne` command line flags are employed to run code over each line of input. Raku's `m/<start>/fff/<stop>/` sed-like "flip-flop" operator is employed which takes linewise input (special-cased within the Rakudo compiler), enabling the return of text blocks that start with the first matching line and stop with the second matching line. The variable `$i` is `state`d once at the beginning of the loop to equal `0` zero. Finally, Raku also allows code blocks to execute within Regexes upon matching.

Putting it all together, when the `sed`-like "flip-flop" operator encounters a full match in both (start,stop) halves of the `fff` regex operator, `$i` gets incremented to 1, and thus `last`s out of the loop, so only the first complete match is `put`. [If you want to output all matches, simply omit the `{last if $i++ == 1}` code block].

Note, it's simple enough to omit the two 'sentinal' lines in the return by changing `fff` to `^fff^`, giving the following result:

Sample Output (2):

```
content1
content2
```

Further testing: All code above handles the case where P2 comes before P1. Additionally, all code above handles the case where P1 and P2 occur on the same line, WITHOUT terminating prematurely. If such "single line text blocks" are desired/preferred in the output, use Raku's "non-sed-like" `ff` operator instead of the `fff` operator.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/fff
https://raku.org