# modify between (only) 1st occurrence of patterns (inclusive of patterns) and keep processing

Tags: awk, gawk

There are several questions about matching between only the first occurrence of two patterns (e.g., [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180663/how-to-select-first-occurrence-between-two-patterns-including-them)) — but they all seem to rely on `exit`, which is no good, as I want to keep processing the file.

What I want to do is modify the first occurrence of a range between patterns (but not other occurrences) and do other awk foo. Specifically, I'm trying to comment in/out some sections of a dovecot conf file. In a truly ideal world, I'd want a single line* that makes sure the `userdb { driver = prefetch }` block is un-commented, and all other `userdb { }` blocks are commented. But since the file is at least a little predictable, I was aiming for uncommenting the first commented block, and then commenting all others.

I have

```
... some stuff that should be echoed as is ...
#userdb {
#  driver = prefetch
#}
... more stuff
userdb {
  driver = sql
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
}
... still more stuff
#userdb {
  #driver = static
  #args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
#}
```

And I want

```
... original stuff ...
userdb {
  driver = prefetch
}
... more stuff
#userdb {
#  driver = sql
#  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
#}
... still more stuff
#userdb {
  #driver = static
  #args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
#}
```

I thought I was going to get somewhere with setting a flag in awk, thusly:

```
awk '/^#userdb/,/^#}/ && !ididit {
        print substr($0,2);
        next;
        ididit=1;
    }
    /^userdb/,/}/ {
        print "#", $0;
        next
    }
    {print}' auth-sql.conf.ext
```

Which was oh-so-close, but setting my `ididit` flag (I added a bunch of prints, just to make sure it was actually getting set) doesn't cut it:

```
... original stuff ...
userdb {
  driver = prefetch
}
... more stuff
# userdb {
#   driver = sql
#   args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
# }
... more stuff ...
userdb {
 #driver = static
 #args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/vmail/%u
}
```

Note the last `userdb {}` block managed to get itself uncommented. This was quite vexing, until I found [deep in the bowels](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk-3.0.3/html_chapter/gawk_9.html) of GNU awk docs this little gem:

> `echo Yes | awk '/1/,/2/ || /Yes/'`
>
> The author of this program intended
>   it to mean `(/1/,/2/) || /Yes/`. However, awk interprets this as
>   `/1/, (/2/ || /Yes/)`. This cannot be changed or worked around; range
>   patterns do not combine with other patterns.

So, my little `&& !ididit` is a non-starter.

Any suggestions on how I can make this (or better, my "In a truly ideal world", from above) happen on a single line*? `perl` is not an option, but `sed` or even `bash` could be.

* "a single line" can be a fairly complex line, though I'd still like it to be understandable, and throw a reasonable exit code — I'm trying to put this into an AWS CloudFormation template.

FWIW

```
$awk -V
GNU Awk 4.0.2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please (1) write a clearer, more concise and precise explanation of what you want to do, (2) put it *before* the examples, (3) make the examples shorter and clearer, and (4) break your `awk` command into shorter lines, so it doesn’t require horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Done. Hopefully that's better/clearer. Let me know if you want further edits.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a philosophy
that you should do as much testing as possible
in the “patterns” in `awk` scripts (i.e., the things before the `{`). 
I was programming in C and other languages long before I encountered `awk`,
so I’m not reluctant to use an `if` statement (or three)
when it seems appropriate.

So here’s what I came up with:

```
awk '/userdb/,/}/ {
        if (!comment) {                         # Uncomment the first one
                sub("#", "")
                print
                if ($0 ~ /}/) comment=1         # All others get commented
        } else {
                if ($0 ~ /^[[:blank:]]*#/) {    # Already commented out?
                        print
                } else {
                        print "#" $0
                }
        }
        next
      }
      { print }
    '
```

It’s clearly based on your code. 
`comment` is a variable analogous to your `ididit`;
it is initially 0 (false), and gets set to 1 (true)
after the first block has been processed.

Within a `/userdb/` - `/}/` block,

- If we’re uncommenting,

  - use `sub` to remove a `#`, if any. 
    This is safer than unconditionally ripping off the first character
    — what if the code is *already* uncommented?
  - When we see the `}` (marking the end of the block),
    set the `comment` flag, so all future matches will be commented out.
- If we’re commenting,

  - if the line is already commented, just print it as is,
  - otherwise, put a `#` in front.

Note that the uncommenting code assumes that
the first block does not *contain* any comments. 
For example,

```
userdb {
  driver = prefetch     # We want to keep this uncommented.
}
```

would be changed to

```
userdb {
  driver = prefetch      We want to keep this uncommented.
}
```

which looks like it would be an error.