# How do I select only the first set of lines matching a regex in sed?

Tags: shell, sed

I have the following regex that works for me in sed:

```
cat <<EOF | sed -E '/^([A-Z][a-z]+){2,}$/Q'
Nothing Relevant
TotallyFake:

- NowWeWant
- TheseLines
- AndAlsoThisLine                                                                                                       

ButNotThisLine
- OrThisLine          
EOF
```

This only outputs the lines we want... but also the header lines, which is less good. So I lookes around and found the `/this/,/that/` approach, and thought, cool! I can find the first PascalishCase thing and then break at the first empty line.

So I tried this:

```
cat <<EOF | sed -En '/^- ([A-Z][a-z]+){2,}$/,/^$/p'

Nothing Relevant
TotallyFake:

- NowWeWant
- TheseLines
- AndAlsoThisLine

ButNotThisLine
- OrThisLine
EOF
```

However... it gives me `OrThisLine`. which is far less desirable.

How can I just use sed to find the first block of PascalText beginning with a `-`  and only print those lines?

[edit]

Since the contents weren't clear enough, the output I want is:

```
- NowWeWant
- TheseLines
- AndAlsoThisLine
```

My understanding was that `/this/,/that/` would find the first `this` and go to the first `that` after "this", but the `^$` pattern  isn't matching the first blank line, it appears to be matching EOF.

Comment: It's unclear what the expected output should be for the two pipelines (you allude to something about getting the lines from the first  PascalCase line to the next empty one, but it's unclear what lines these are). Also, please specify whether the document is a YAML document, in which case there may be much better tools than `sed` to process it, depending on what it is you're actually wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a YAML file like this (the indentation of the array elements is optional):

```yaml
---
Somesection:
Someothersection:
TotallyFake:
  - NowWeWant
  - TheseLines
  - AndAlsoThisLine

ButNotThisLine:
  - OrThisLine
```

... and that you want to get the elements of the top-level `TotallyFake` array.

You would extract the `TotallyFake` top-level array (as YAML) using Mike Farah's `yq` (the most commonly available `yq` on Linux) like so:

```bash
$ yq '.TotallyFake' file
- NowWeWant
- TheseLines
- AndAlsoThisLine
```

Would you want the elements of the `TotallyFake` array as individual lines, expand the array by adding `[]` at the end:

```bash
$ yq '.TotallyFake[]' file
NowWeWant
TheseLines
AndAlsoThisLine
```

The corresponding commands using Andrey Kislyuk's `yq` (a wrapper around the well known `jq` JSON processor):

```bash
$ yq -y '.TotallyFake' file
- NowWeWant
- TheseLines
- AndAlsoThisLine
```

Here, the `-y` option tells `yq` to extract the data as YAML.  Without it we would get a JSON-encoded array back (the equivalent of `["NowWeWant","TheseLines","AndAlsoThisLine"]`).

To get the element as separate lines:

```bash
$ yq -r '.TotallyFake[]' file
NowWeWant
TheseLines
AndAlsoThisLine
```

The `-r` option gives us decoded ("raw") strings.

---

With `sed`, treating the input as text rather than a document in a structured document format:

```bash
$ sed -e '/^TotallyFake:/,/^$/!d' -e '//d' file
- NowWeWant
- TheseLines
- AndAlsoThisLine
```

This deletes all the lines that are outside of the section that we're interested in, and then deletes the actual range start and end lines with a second `d` command.  The empty regular expression is a special syntax that tells `sed` to reuse the most recently match regular expression.

Note that this *relies* on whitespace that is optional in YAML documents (the empty line after the last element of the `TotallyFake` array).

Comment: definitely not YAML, also I can't guarantee that there's anything before the first `- CamelCaseWord`.

Comment: Turns out this was close! And apparently I misunderstood how sed does marker patterns - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180729/5788 looks like it finds *every* `/A/,/B/` set. `sed -E '/- ([A-Z][a-z]+){2,}/,/^$/!d;/^$/q'` does exactly what I need.

Comment: And more particularly, since I'm trying to also get rid of the leading `- `: `sed -E '/- ([A-Z][a-z]+){2,}/,/^$/!d;s/^- //;/^$/q'` is completely what I needed